# Hiding node group input (compositor)

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, customization

[image]

To compact my node (it will allow to add more adjustments) I would like to hide unused inputs. With dropdown list I could unhide chosen adjustment. That would be awesome if unhided adjustment will be added as a new field. Is it possible?

If not, is there any way to hide the group inputs with simple switch. For an example those 4 I have marked by red color will be hided in one field "adjustment" that will unfold when ticked.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the node and select `Toggle Hidden Node Sockets` or press <kbd>Ctrl H</kbd>

Comment: Right- click on the node doesn't work in 2.82
CRTL-H is hiding all unused sockets. This is not what I'm trying to do.